# How to re-link .tga files to .FBX model?

Tags: materials, transparency

I need to re-link all the textures to a fence. I managed to see the chain links by adding the opacity texture, but instead  of there being transparency, they are black. I had also tried adding the Diffuse texture, but it would make the black turn white and it actually looks like it is a "scratch" texture but it was kind of floating vertically on the plane instead of wrapping around the tubes. The file I have are: .FBX, Opacity, Diffuse, and RGB which in the description on the website I bough it from: :is laid out in this fashion; Red - Roughness Blue - Ambient Occlusion Green - Metallness

I had already made a post with a simpler question but it was marked as an already answered question while it doesn't really explain what nodes to use to hook up the .tga textures that I have to connect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Have you tried plugging the alpha output of the image texture node into the alpha input of the shader ?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. This is the result with both color and alpha in, same result even if I only connect alpha. Thank for replying.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: If you're using Eevee (or material preview), go to the Materials property panel and check what "Blend Mode" is set.  You might need to change it to "Alpha Blend."

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the object, re-import it and apply the texture again for it to work.